# Using ngZone with rxjs subcribe

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, zone

Inside my function `getNext()` i'm filling variables asynchonously via subscrybing observable function. When variable is filled i want to call a function `next()` of my `ViewChild` component `ngslCarousel` which is using there variables inside html logic. I don't know why, but the method is not work.

```
this.pages.getNext()
          .subscribe((page: IListItemsPage<Ads>) => {
              this.zone.run(() => {
                this.pages.push(page);
                this.ads = page.items;
                this.hasNext = page.hasNext;
                this.hasPrev = true;
                this.index++;
                this.adsCount = this.adsCount - page.items.length;
                this.ngslCarousel.next();
              });
            });
```

`pages`, `ads` are global variables which are used by `this.ngslCarousel.next();`

To notice, if i use `setTimeout()` everything works not bad, but this solution is not looking right.

```
setTimeout(() => {
              this.ngslCarousel.next();
            }, 250);
```

Comment: Do your componets have `OnPush` change detection strategy?

Comment: @xyz Nope, id rather say this is Default Change Detection Strategy.

Comment: All RxJS subscriptions should be registered with zone automatically.  Does it work if you remove the `this.zone.run`?

Comment: @Pace No, only if i use setTimeout

Comment: Have you confirmed the subscription is actually firing multiple times?  For example, the Angular HTTP calls will fire once and then complete.  I don't see any calls to `interval` or anything obvious that would mean `getNext()` would repeat every 250ms

Comment: Please, create a minimal reproducible example of this — we probably will be of better help then. You could use any 3rd party repl platform, e.g. https://stackblitz.com/.